# Required Field Validator not Working For DropDownList

Tags: asp.net

Why is the validator not working here. It's working fine for other textbox controls though.
There is no error. Its just does the postback.

```
<asp:DropDownList Id="ddlCustomer" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true"
 DataTextField="customername" DataValueField="customerid">
<asp:ListItem Text="--Select--" Value="0"></asp:ListItem> 
<asp:ListItem Text=" < Add New > " Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="ddlCustomer"
cssclass="required" display="dynamic" errormessage="*" setfocusonerror="true"
initialvalue="--Select--"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`initialValue` should be "0" not the Text "--Select--"

like below

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="ddlCustomer"
cssclass="required" display="dynamic" errormessage="*" setfocusonerror="true"
initialvalue="0"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Comment: Thank you that worked. But is it always have to be value instead of text. If the value prop. is not defined , then it will work with just th text prop...right?

Comment: No it wouldn't work as well. you have to specify the initialvalue

Answer (score 3):

You have given the initial value as `--Select--` in `RequiredFieldValidator` but there is no item which has the value as `--Select--`, RequiredFieldValidtor fires when it get the item's value which is equal to `InitialValue`. So in this case it will never fire.

You need to put the value as `0` in the `InitialValue` of validator or change the value of first item of DropDown.

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="ddlCustomer"
cssclass="required" display="dynamic" errormessage="*" setfocusonerror="true"
InitialValue="0"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

OR

```
<asp:ListItem Text="--Select--" Value="--Select--"></asp:ListItem>
```

But I'd recommend you to use the first approach.